# gTTS direct output

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I want to make a chatbot's response in **audio** and text.

All the example code using gTTS seem like one needs to 'save the text into a file then play the file'.

Is there another way to simplify the process such as, play the 'response from chatbot' automatically, using gTTS?

Comment: What examples did you look at? There are three examples in the docs, and only one of them requires `save`. They even call the section for the last one ["Playing sound directly"](http://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#playing-sound-directly).

Comment: well, you'll still have to type in 'hello' first. Is there a way to pass a variable and play it?

Comment: `gTTS` doesn't know or care whether the string comes from a variable or a literal in your code, same as every other function in Python. Just like you can type `print('hello')` or `print(my_variable)`, you can type `gTTS('hello', 'en')` or `gTTS(my_variable, 'en')`.

Comment: I c. Good to know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look even briefly at [the docs](http://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#playing-sound-directly), you'll see that, of the three examples, only one of them requires you to call `save`, and the third one is specifically called "Playing sound directly".

So, just do exactly what's in that example, but substitute your string in place of the literal `'hello'`:

```
>>> from gtts import gTTS
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>>
>>> my_variable = 'hello' # your real code gets this from the chatbot
>>> 
>>> mp3_fp = BytesIO()
>>> tts = gTTS(my_variable, 'en')
>>> tts.write_to_fp(mp3_fp)
```

But notice that gTTS doesn't come with an MP3 player; you need a separate audio library to play that `mp3_fp` buffer:

```
>>> # Load `audio_fp` as an mp3 file in
>>> # the audio library of your choice
```

As the docs say, there are many such libraries, and Stack Overflow is not a good place to get recommendations for libraries. I happen to have a library installed, named [`musicplayer`](https://github.com/albertz/music-player-core), and a sample app that can be easily adapted here, but it's probably not the simplest one by a long shot (it's made for doing more powerful, low-level stuff):

```
>>> import musicplayer
>>> class Song:
...     def __init__(self, f):
...         self.f = f
...     def readPacket(self, size):
...         return self.f.read(size)
...     def seekRaw(self, offset, whence):
...         self.f.seek(offset, whence)
...         return f.tell()
>>> player = musicplayer.createPlayer()
>>> player.queue = [Song(mp3_fp)]
>>> player.playing = True
```

Comment: musicplayer seems to be inactive on github are there any other known alternatives

Answer (score 3):

if you want to call speak function again and again without any error.

Basically, this serves the purpose.

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import playsound

def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang='en')

    filename = "abc.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)
    os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the solution that I found is by using pygame.mixer. In this case, import time is only used to ensure audio finishes before program ends.

```
from gtts import gTTS
from io import BytesIO
from pygame import mixer
import time

def speak():
    mp3_fp = BytesIO()
    tts = gTTS('hello, Welcome to Python Text-to-Speech!', lang='en')
    tts.write_to_fp(mp3_fp)
    return mp3_fp

mixer.init()
sound = speak()
sound.seek(0)
mixer.music.load(sound, "mp3")
mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Linux] Speech in Python

#### Installation

1. [Terminal] Upgrade pip: `pip install --upgrade pip`
2. [Terminal] Install Google Text to Speech: `pip install gTTS`
3. [Terminal] Install pygame: `pip install pygame`
4. [Coding IDE] Add `speech.py`: See listing below
5. [Coding IDE] Call `speak`: See listing below

#### speech.py

```py
from gtts import gTTS
from io import BytesIO
import pygame

class Speech():

    @classmethod
    def speak(cls, text):
        mp3_file_object = BytesIO()
        tts = gTTS(text, lang='en')
        tts.write_to_fp(mp3_file_object)
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(mp3_file_object, 'mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

#### Example

```py
from .speech import Speech
Speech.speak('hello world')
```

#### Warning

It's a female voice and sounds realistic. It sounds like there's a woman in the room, fwiw.

Comment: What is the purpose of the class structure? Is that just a style thing?

Comment: @ShepBryan, to clarify your question, you would want the code to be just `speak` and `stop` and `goFaster`, not `Speech.speak`, `Speech.stop` or `Speech.goFaster`?

Answer (score -6):

You can also use the playsound library.

`>>>import playsound`

`>>>playsound.playsound('sound.mp3')`

For more information on playsound.Visit [Playsound Docs](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) .