# Is there a module that allows me to make Python say things as audio? Through the microphone

Tags: python, pygame, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I already understand how to use gTTS, (Google's Text to Speech module), but I am not sure how to make everything it says into input audio!
Basically, I want to make the program that says things through my mic, and anyone listening on the other end will be able to hear this!

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

You could use the following methods.

### Method-1: Microsoft speech engine (Tested on Windows 10)

On Windows 10 platform, you could use the following alternative.

```py
import win32com.client as wincl
speaker = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak("Hello World")
```

### Method-2: Use `gtts` + `pygame` (OS Independent Solution)

Here you could use `gtts` to save the text as an mp3 file and then load and play it using `pygame`.

#### Step-1: Saving Text as MP3 file

```py
#pip install gTTS
from gtts import gTTS
tts = gTTS(text='Good morning', lang='en')
tts.save("good.mp3")
```

#### Step-2: Loading and Playing the MP3 file

```py
#pip install pygame
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('good.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

**Another option**: Use VLC MediaPlayer to play the MP3 file.

```py
#pip install python-vlc
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("good.mp3")
p.play()
```

### Method-3: Directly Text-to-Speech Playing from Buffer

No need to save as an mp3 file.

Source:

1. [gTTS direct output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164040/gtts-direct-output)
2. https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#playing-sound-directly
3. https://gist.github.com/lamegaton/1c7f383d6434a9b02f5652ddbee258d9

```py
from gtts import gTTS
from io import BytesIO

# Use gTTS to Store Speech on Buffer
tts = gTTS(text='Good morning', lang='en')
mp3 = BytesIO()
tts.write_to_fp(mp3)
mp3.seek(0)

# Play from Buffer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(mp3)
mixer.music.play()
```

### References

1. https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/text-to-speech/
2. https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/
3. [Playing mp3 song on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python)

Comment: I use Mac, sorry for not specifying, is there anything else?

Comment: Nice! Does this play through the microphone? So if I have friends listening through a voice chat like discord, perhaps, will it will play the noise and they will hear it.

Comment: @jetlikesferraris Yes. I tried all of them and they do play through a microphone. Please consider **voting up** and **accepting** if you think this answer helped. For accepting this answer you will need to click on the “tick mark” on the left of the answer. And it will turn green.